# Must $f$ necessarily be integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $c \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$. Let $f$ be a non-negative, real-valued, measurable function defined on $[0,1]$ satisfying $\lambda \cdot m(\{x \in [0,1]:f(x)\geq \lambda\})\leq c/ \lambda$ for each $\lambda >0$.

My question is, must $f$ necessarily be integrable?

I know that $ \lambda \cdot m(\{x \in [0,1]:f(x)\geq \lambda\}) \leq \int_Ef$ by Chebyshev's inequality. However, I don't think this helps because the inequality is the "wrong" way. Therefore, I suspect that $f$ is not required to be integrable, although I can't think of a counterexample. I tried setting $f(x)=\begin{cases} 1/x,x \neq0 \\ 0,x=0 \end{cases}$, which I already know is not integrable, but this function has $\lambda \cdot m(\{x \in [0,1]:f(x)\geq \lambda\})=1 \nleq c/ \lambda$ for each $\lambda$ sufficiently large.

Comment: Do you want $\lambda \cdot m(\{x \in [0,1]:f(x)\geq \lambda\})\leq c$ instead?

Comment: @ArcticChar No, actually. I *really* mean $\lambda^2 \cdot m\{x \in [0,1] : f(x) \geq \lambda\} \leq c$.

Comment: Ok. I am confused since $\lambda \cdot m(\{x \in [0,1]:f(x)\geq \lambda\}) \leq \int_Ef$ doesn't have $\lambda^2$ in it., so the Chebyshev's inequality is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: @ArcticChar I agree that the Chebyshev inequality doesn't seem to help here.

Answer (score 2):

Weak type $L^{2,\infty}$ is embedded into $L^{q}$ for $0<q<2$ in finite measure space:
\begin{align*}
\int_{E}|f(x)|^{q}d\mu(x)\leq\dfrac{2}{2-q}\mu(E)^{1-q/2}\|f\|_{L^{2,\infty}}^{q},
\end{align*}
this is an exercise in Loukas Grafakos book *Classical Fourier Analysis*, page 14. Essentially, you need a delicate inequality:
\begin{align*}
\mu(E\cap(|f|>\alpha))\leq\min\left(\mu(E),\alpha^{-2}\|f\|_{L^{2,\infty}}^{2}\right).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is necessarily integrable. $\int_0^{1} f(x)dx=\int_0^{\infty} m( \{x: f(x) >\lambda\}) d\lambda \leq \int_0^{1} 1 d\lambda +\int_1^{\infty} \frac c {\lambda^{2}}d\lambda <\infty$.

Comment: Why is $\int_0 ^1 f=\int _0 ^\infty m(\{x:f(x)> \lambda\}) d \lambda$?

Comment: That is a well known identity proved using Fubini/Tonelli's Theorem , Write $m(f(x) >\lambda)$ as $\int I_{f>\lambda} (y)dy$ and then interchange the integrals w.r.t. $x$ and $y$. The interchange is permissible because the integrand is non-negative.